# multiple checkbox enabled display text, disabled remove text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

are these 2 functions possible using javascript (onclick checkbox to enabled then display text, onclick to disable and then undisplay text)?

1. When ticking a checkbox and then display text (optionally editable). When unticking the same checkbox and removing the text?
2. Having a series of such checkboxes and displaying (or undisplaying) each line of text in the order the checkboxes are listed? (eg 1 line at a time in the order of the checkboxes)

** EDIT - code so far, not working for other options... also is it possible to edit all the text in 1 container? ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Text Maker:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="box" onclick="myFunction()">
<label for="box">Option 1</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="box" onclick="myFunction()">
<label for="box">Option 2</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="box" onclick="myFunction()">
<label for="box">Option 3</label> 

<p id="text" style="display:none">Display Option 1 settings here.</p>
<p id="text" style="display:none">Display Option 2 settings here.</p>
<p id="text" style="display:none">Display Option 3 settings here.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("box");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Either you wanna put `counter` or get unique id from database and put after `box` id like `box1, box2, box4, box5, box9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **this** keyword when calling your function to reference the checkbox that is being clicked, and also pass in the paragraphs id to grab that element.

You can add `contenteditable="true"` to your paragraph tags to make them editable, if I understand you correctly?

```
<p>Text Maker:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" onclick="myFunction(this,'textBox1')">
<label for="box1">Option 1</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="box2" onclick="myFunction(this,'textBox2')">
<label for="box2">Option 2</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="box3" onclick="myFunction(this,'textBox3')">
<label for="box3">Option 3</label> 

<p id="textBox1" style="display:none" contenteditable="true">Display Option 1 settings here.</p>
<p id="textBox2" style="display:none">Display Option 2 settings here.</p>
<p id="textBox3" style="display:none">Display Option 3 settings here.</p>

<script>
function myFunction(checkBoxElm,textBoxId) {
 
  let textBox = document.getElementById(textBoxId);
  if (checkBoxElm.checked){
    textBox.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     textBox.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What if we have thousand of textbox then you give `textBoxId` manually for all checkbox

Comment: I wasn't sure the use case. This will not scale as is for sure, but if it's for a couple of items on a form, or similar given the context, then it should be just okay. I would need to know more about the usage before assuming much else.

Comment: @rolewest you are correct. It wasn't for thousands of checkboxes/texts, but possibly up to a few dozen. It would be interesting to see how thousands could be managed with checkboxes, but that is out of scope for this case. Thanks for the response, works great :)

Answer (score 0):

When having multiple inputs with the same identity class name works better. So you can add a class name to the inputs and then use each function to achieve what you are trying to do.

The following inputs are having the same class name and now you can use each function as follows:

`

```js
$ = jQuery;
$('.box').each(function(){
            
    $(this).change(function() { // on change of any of the input either checked or unchecked

        if(this.checked){ // if the input is checked
             alert('checked'); // your css
        }else{ // if the input is unchecked
             alert('not checked'); // your css
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="box">
<label for="box">Option 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box">
<label for="box">Option 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box">
```

Comment: OP never said they were using JQuery though...